# Use AutocompleteEditText with PlacesAutocomplete Api in Android With Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

I'm using an application with Android and Kotlin and trying to use an AutocompleteEditText with the PlacesAutocomplete api. I have created an adapter for AutocompleteEditText and the data obtained well, but the drop-down menu and the connected data are not displayed correctly.

Debuggin realized that the data obtained after the return of the filterResult.
He saw that maybe it could be solved with Kotlin Coroutines but he didn't.
Can someone help me solve this problem?

I leave the code.

Thank you

This is the adapter:

```
class PlacesAutocompleteAdapter(
    context: Context,
    private val resource: Int,
    private var objects: List<AutocompletePrediction>,
    private val placesClient: PlacesClient
) : ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction>(context, resource, objects), Filterable {


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, parent, false);


        val tv = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1) as TextView
        tv.text = objects.get(position).toString()
        return view;
    }

    fun updateData(data : List<AutocompletePrediction>){
        objects = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        val filter : Filter = object : Filter() {

            override fun publishResults(p0: CharSequence?, p1: FilterResults?) {
                if ((p1 != null) && (p1.count > 0)){


                }

            }

            override fun performFiltering(p0: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

                var filterResult : FilterResults = FilterResults()
                if (p0 != null && p0.count()>2){
                    var request : Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> = placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.newInstance(p0.toString()))
                    var filterResults : FilterResults = FilterResults()
                    while (!request.isComplete){

                    }

                    filterResult.values  = request.getResult()?.autocompletePredictions
                    filterResult.count = request.getResult()?.autocompletePredictions!!.count()


                }
                return filterResult
            }
        }


        return filter
    }
}
```

And this is how i set the adapter to AutocompleteEditText

```
override fun setTextListeners() {

    originAdapter =  PlacesAutocompleteAdapter(
        this, // Context
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, // Layout
        ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>(), // Array,
        this.placesClient// placesClient
    )
    originAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true)
    originDesc.setAdapter(originAdapter)


    destinationAdapter = PlacesAutocompleteAdapter(
        this, // Context
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, // Layout
        ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>(), // Array,
        this.placesClient// placesClient
    )
    destinationAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true)
    destinationDesc.setAdapter(destinationAdapter)


}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem you're having? Are the place autocomplete predictions not showing up correctly, or at all? Are you getting any errors?